# Applying html formating in label control

Tags: asp.net, html, formatting, coding-style

The html formating is applied great in this case.
The Surname is displayed with size 5.

```
lblWelcome.Text = "Welcome:<font size=''5''>" & txtSurname.Text & "</font>"
```

Why the html style is not applied in this example?

```
lblWelcome.Text = "Welcome:<font color=''white''>" & txtSurname.Text & "</font>"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, please, please don't use font tags. Also, if you really want to output HTML from the server side then you should be using a Literal control.

Here is an example of how I would do it:

aspx/ascx file:

```
Welcome: <asp:Literal id="lit1" runat="server" />
```

code behind:

```
lit1.Text = "<span class='welcome'>" & txtSurname.Text & "</span>"
```

OR your other example:

```
lit1.Text = "<span class='welcomeBig'>" & txtSurname.Text & "</span>"
```

css:

```
span.welcome { color:#fff; }
span.welcomeBig { font-size:24px; }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I guess CSS overides everything! I got the desired style without even using the literal control

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you could use the ASP.NET [Literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode.aspx) web control and set its Mode property to Encode or Transform.

```
Literal1.Mode = LiteralMode.Encode

Literal.Text = "Welcome:<font color='white'>" & txtSurname.Text & "</font>"
```

In the above code, the HTML elements will be transformed into proper HTML, leaving just the surname text in white.

Comment: I have tried Encode, Transform and PassThrough but it didn't work out. +1 for the literal control :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just set the ForeColor property on the Label.

```
lblWelcome.Text = txtSurname.Text;
lblWelcome.ForeColor = "white";
```

You'd have to put the 'Welcome' outside the label, but it would probably make more logical sense.

```
Welcome:<asp:Label id="lblWelcome" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Even though it doesn't directly answer the question, this is +1 simply because outputting font tags is really 1996...

Comment: @womp - sometimes the answer is there is a better way. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Also don't forget to HTML encode the surname: `Server.HtmlEncode(txtSurname.Text);`